# Visual Studio 2012 Express Web ignores Unit Tests

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

a quickie, that you might already have solved :

I have a Test Project created in VS2010 SP1. The Project is imported into VS2012 Express. The Test Explorer Window shows no Tests (although there are two for now). So I click "run all", which results in the following Console Output (roughly translated, don't know the exact unlocalized equivalent) :

```
========== Build: 0 successful, 0 erroneous, 2 current, 0 skipped ==========
```

No Results, no Tests in Test Explorer...Any ideas?

TIA!

Comment: Imported, how? As in added an existing project or by recreating the project and adding the classes manually?

Comment: Can you check the test output. Open Output Window and change the dropdown from build to tests.

Comment: Imported = the solution was opened in VS2012, Do you think it would make sense to create a new Project and add the files manually?

Comment: @allen, The test output is empty. Looks like VS only builds and then stops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, the problem was based on the fact that the test class library was created in VS 2010. On the following screenshot,you can see the project that gets ignored by the VS 2012 test runner (bottom icon) and a newly created c# .Net 4.0 Test Project with all tests being executed as intended (topmost icon).

[image: Project variations]